# How does DEFINE_TYPE_NAME in Boost work?

Tags: c++, boost

I thought I know C++. Wrong.

```
template<typename T>
struct string_type_name;
#define DEFINE_TYPE_NAME(Type) \
template<> struct string_type_name<Type> \
{ \
static char const * _() \
{ \
return #Type; \
} \
}
DEFINE_TYPE_NAME(float);
DEFINE_TYPE_NAME(double);
DEFINE_TYPE_NAME(long double);
```

Code from [Boost.Math](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/master/quaternion/quaternion_test.cpp). What does this macro do and why is it needed? What does `template<>` mean, having no arguments? Why are we declaring this function `static char const * _()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just expand the macro:

```
template<typename T>
struct string_type_name;

template<> struct string_type_name<float>
{
  static char const * _()
  {
    return "float";
  }
}

template<> struct string_type_name<double>
{
  static char const * _()
  {
    return "double";
  }
}

template<> struct string_type_name<long double>
{
  static char const * _()
  {
    return "long double";
  }
}
```

Each the constructs beginning with `template<>` are specialisations of the `string_type_name` class declared above. You'll notice that the unspecialised template doesn't actually have a definition - that's to prevent you from instantiating it with a type that is not one of the ones that have been specialised.

The `_` function (not a very nice name) returns a `char const*`, which is the string literal denoting the type that it has been specialised for. That is, it's just a mapping from types to strings: `string_type_name<float>::_()` would return `"float"`. You can see how they're using it below:

```
BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Testing multiplication for "
    << string_type_name<T>::_() << ".");
```

Comment: C++ 11 adds support for function objects - objects that override the () operator and act essentially as function pointers. I suspect that's why boost is using this rather bizarre function name.

Comment: How does `string_type_name<float>::_(){ return #Type;}`   translate to `return "float";`?

Comment: @ventsyv `operator()` is not new to C++11. If they were overloading `operator()`, you would have to create an instance of the type before calling `()` on it. They wanted the `static` function call syntax instead.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html).

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield They are obviously not overriding operator(), but are rather following the function object syntax for consistency. At least that's how it appears to me, otherwise they could have used a meaningful function name.